# Simple preg_replace returns null

Tags: php, regex

Why is this very simple preg_replace is returning null ?

```
preg_replace('[\s]+', '', "test test")
```

the idea was to remove spaces.

Comment: Turn on error reporting: `Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '+' `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forget to add delimiters.

```
preg_replace('~\s+~', '', "test test");
```

And also it's better to use `\s+` instead of `[\s]+` in your pattern.

Comment: I really should have read the PHP pattern syntax (http://bit.ly/UNz6Nm) before asking. Specially the delimiter part (http://bit.ly/1smCR8w). I only tested it on-line, but the on-line test don't have the need for delimiters. Thanks to all who answered.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is wrong, there are no beginning and ending slashes:

```
preg_replace('/[\s]+/', '', "test test");
```

Comment: backslashes aren't the only solution. The right answer is that he need delimiters, and of course backslashes are delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

Another way with delimiter `[` & `]`:

```
preg_replace('[\s+]', '', "test test")
```

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira: yes they are.

Comment: but doing that way may confuse people with the meaning of the metacharacters [].